# Could not find any React Native Android projects in your branch - Code Push

Tags: react-native, code-push

I am working on a react-native project, application and everything is perfectly working but when I try to configure build on code push it shows something like -

```
We couldn’t find any React Native Android projects in your branch.
```

[image]

Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by increase gitlab resource due to this problem came from too large size polling from gitlab now fixed Hope this help.

Comment: how to increase this gitlab resource? any doc available ?

Answer (score -1):

Same issue
using react-native 0.59
no any special config